# onvif soap message request using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, onvif

I am trying to communicate with an onvif camera on the browser but have not success so far. Below is the code that i am using to communicate with the onvif camera.

```js
let soapMessage = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">' +
                  '<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'+
                  '<GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/>'+
                  '</s:Body>'+
                  '</s:Envelope>';

let ipAdd = '192.168.1.100';
let port = 80;
let path = '/onvif/device_service';

let url = `http://${ipAdd}:${port}${path}`;
$.ajax(
{
  type : 'POST',
  url,
  contentType : 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
  dataType: "xml",
  processData: false,
  data  : soapMessage,
  success : processSuccess,
  error  : processError 
});

function processSuccess(data, status, req) 
{
  console.log( 'SUCCESS' );
    }

function processError(data, status, req) 
{
  console.log( 'ERROR' );
}
```

i am getting a `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

what i am doing wrong. Help needed

Answer (score 0):

My working example basing on your question:

```js
var soapMessage = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">' +
                  '<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'+
                  '<GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/>'+
                  '</s:Body>'+
                  '</s:Envelope>';
                  


var ipAdd = '192.168.2.110';
var port = 80;
var path = '/onvif/device_service';

var wsurl = `http://${ipAdd}:${port}${path}`;
jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: wsurl,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: false,
        data: soapMessage,
        success: processSuccess,
        error: processError
    });

}
```